# How to rotate the head text in jspdf autotable?

Tags: jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I need to rotate the text of the head text, is there any way we can achieve that.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using typescript:

```
    doc.text('TEXT HERE', 50, 50, {angle:90});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
doc.text(30, 30, 'YOUR HEAD TEXT HERE', null, 90);
```

90-The angle of rotation